# Reading HTML into R

Tags: r

I am trying to read in the HTML code for a website into R but I keep encountering an error

```
> data=readLines("www.google.com")
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'www.google.com': No such file or directory
```

I tried to the following command prior to establish a connection.

```
> setInternet2(TRUE)
Error: 'setInternet2' is defunct.
See help("Defunct")
```

I also tried installing the library and updating R but with no luck.

```
library(installr)
updateR()
```

What do I need to get R to load the HTML code?

Comment: You need to add the "http://" to properly specify a url address.   Also take a look at the `rvest` package for reading a parsing html code.

Comment: Thank you! But what if your trying to access a site and you get this error message from the readLines command "Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection. HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'"

Comment: Does the site require a log in?